# Every version of IE opening links in new window

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, window, target

I've been designing a website and have been using Safari and Chrome for most of the testing. I just tried testing Firefox and that went smoothly too. Leave it to IE to throw in a wrench.

For some reason, every link opens a new window, for every single version from IE 6 to IE 10. In the metro version of IE 10, they open in new tabs.

My only thought is that I didn't specify the target="_self", but shouldn't that be implied? Is there a solution without adding target="_self" to every single link in my website?

Comment: Can you post the html of the link? Is there a javascript event that is firing when you click on the link? Maybe inspect the link and watch if changes occur on the html when you click on it. Is this happening to just your computer or to all client browsers. It just seems that your website has a problem somewhere.

Comment: Check out the remarks section here, maybe useful - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms534659(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Here is an example of a link. Nothing fancy. <a href="/connect/rides/">Dashboard</a> It is happening when using browserstack.com. I haven't tested native IE as I am using a mac. However, none of the other browsers on browserstack.com seem to have this problem.

Comment: Additionally, it is strange that a link like this doesn't work at all in IE, yet works in everything else. <a href="/connect/rides/forgot"><button class="large gray" type="button">Forgot Password</button></a>

Comment: i think it could be a problem on your computer. Try disabling internet security software. This problem is on the fringe of being off topic here.

Comment: your problem could belong to SuperUser.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your suggestions. I was able to hop on a physical computer's version of IE, and while certain links are still broken, they do not open in new windows.

I guess this is just an issue with browserstack.com. But considering browserstack is a website specifically designed to test browsers on native operating systems, this really is something they should look into.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble you had earlier Luke. We have now completely fixed the issue. Feel free to get back to us at support@browserstack.com. - Umang @ BrowserStack

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Links. The problem is the leading `/` (slash) in `/basedir/controller/action`.
The solution is to define a `<base>` tag in your HTML head.

You can automate this tag for testing => production environment if you'r using YII:

```
<?php echo '<base href="'.$this->createAbsoluteUrl('/').'/" />'.PHP_EOL; ?>
```

You can even define a target in your `<base>` tag: `target="_self"`