# All links open in new tab on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, browserstack

I feel weird saying this, but every link in my app opens a new tab in IE8. There's no target attribute set. I'm using IE8 in Browserstack, in case that matters. I also have HTML5Shiv, bootstrap3 CSS & JS on the page. Removing support for IE is, unfortunately, not an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913804/every-version-of-ie-opening-links-in-new-window
This is a duplicate answer.

Comment: make it an answer and I'll mark it correct